# How to establish a bidirectional one-to-one mapping between float and int values in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, int

It's known that both float and int require 4 bytes for storage in primitive arrays in Java. Hence, a float value can be mapped to an int value which has the same internal 32 bit representation.

How to establish a computationally inexpensive one-to-one mapping between float and int? For example, the mapping can map 3.2345f to -67567575 and map -67567575 back to a value close to 3.2345f, and most float values (can ignore NaN or Infinity) can be covered. The order or meaning of the mapping doesn't matter.

(The reason I need this is to tackle a problem regarding a jcuda kernel function I am implementing; using other methods are more troublesome for my problem. Need an answer directly on this question instead of ones recommending other methods so on and so forth.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Float.floatToIntBits(floatValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits(float)) for float->int conversion and [`Float.intBitsToFloat(intValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)) for int->float conversion. As the javadoc for `intBitsToFloat` states:

> public static float intBitsToFloat(int bits)
>
> Returns the float value corresponding to a given bit representation.

And the other:

> public static int floatToIntBits(float value)
>
> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout.